# Database design for booking system

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I am creating a booking application for medical office and I am little bit stuck how to organize my database.

These are some of the requirements:
- Owner can create Doctors who work in the office
- Owner can specify working hours for each Doctor for each date
- Customers can book appointment to 30 mins or 1 hour (depending on service)

I am stuck on point where I need to define doctor's availability and present that to customer.

Some of the tables I would have:

```
Doctor
- ID
- Full Name

Customer
- ID
- Full Name

Appointment
- ID
- Doctor ID
- Customer ID
- Time??
```

How to go with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Use iCalendar RRULEs and EXDATEs to represent schedules. There are plenty of libraries to calculate actual dates from these rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a new table that stores the doctor and their working hours. Then, when booking an appointment, you simply check if the doctor works during those hours. Now in order to take lunch breaks or any other non-working hours, you'll need to create a second record for the next duration of working hours.

So to check if they are working at a certain time or to get their working hours, you'd query the table for records on the date and doctor you'd like.

Doctor_Hours

- ID
- Doctor ID
- Date / time start
- Date / time end

1 john 01/01/2015 06:00 01/01/2015 12:00

1 john 01/01/2015 13:00 01/01/2015 18:00